# how to Release our Application

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can anybody help me for  making a distribution build of our app and final release what and all steps we should follow to make a distribution build

Comment: There's an apple guide for this. It's on the front page of the iPhone dev center.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this blog](http://aztekapps.wordpress.com/tutorials/preparing-binary-for-submission/).It will help you understand each and every minute details.

Cheers

Comment: Gah! That blog lost me at Comic Sans. Sorry for the OT.